# How can I use event.target.id as a jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to populate an array/delete elements based on checkboxes being checked or unchecked. Here is the function in question:

```
    function setPresentPlayers() {
    $("#playerAbsent").change(function(event) {
        /** @type {Array}.<string> */
        var player = event.target.id.split('.');
        if ($(event.target.id).attr("checked")) {
            presentPlayers[player[1]] = players[player[1]][1] + ' ' + players[player[1]][0];
        } else {
            presentPlayers.splice(player[1], 1);
        }
    });
}
```

The if statement never evaluates to true but I can see the correct ID from a `console.log(event.target.id);`

How can I fix the selector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't even need to use the ID, since event.target references an element and jQuery allows for an element to be directly passed:

```
$(event.target)
```

Should be all you need.

Comment: side note(not that he should):  if he wanted to use the id, he'd have to prepend a '#' to what he currently has.  so '#'+event.target.id